# Adding buttons to a JavaScript platform game

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, 2d-games

I made a javascript platform game where a the player can either move left, move right, or jump using
the arrow keys on the keyboard. I would like to be able to do this using the javascript buttons that
I made instead of the keyboard arrow keys.

These are my javascript buttons.

```html
<button id="left" type="button">Left</button>
<button id="up" type="button">Jump</button>
<button id="right" type="button">Right</button>
```

Here is my unedited javascript code that uses that makes it so the character can jump, or move either left or right using the keyboard arrow keys.

```js
var playerXSpeed = 7;
var gravity = 30;
var jumpSpeed = 17;


Player.prototype.update = function(time, state, keys) {
  let xSpeed = 0;
  if (keys.ArrowLeft) xSpeed -= playerXSpeed;
  if (keys.ArrowRight) xSpeed += playerXSpeed;
  let pos = this.pos;
  let movedX = pos.plus(new Vec(xSpeed * time, 0));
  if (!state.level.touches(movedX, this.size, "wall")) {
    pos = movedX;
  }

  let ySpeed = this.speed.y + time * gravity;
  let movedY = pos.plus(new Vec(0, ySpeed * time));
  if (!state.level.touches(movedY, this.size, "wall")) {
    pos = movedY;
  } else if (keys.ArrowUp && ySpeed > 0) {
    ySpeed = -jumpSpeed;
  } else {
    ySpeed = 0;
  }
  return new Player(pos, new Vec(xSpeed, ySpeed));
};
```

Here is the part of the code that checks to see if the arrow keys are either up or down. If the arrow keys are up then the character doesn't move. If they are held down then the character continues to move and doesn't stop until the keys are released. I know that I have to do something more hear so that it interacts with my javascript buttons but I don't know what to do.

```js
function trackKeys(keys) {
  let down = Object.create(null);
  function track(event) {
    if (keys.includes(event.key)) {
      down[event.key] = event.type == "keydown";
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("keydown", track);
  window.addEventListener("keyup", track);
  return down;
}

var arrowKeys =
  trackKeys(["ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "ArrowUp"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add these controls fairly easily by adding event listeners to your buttons' `onmousedown` & `onmouseup` events.

You should also avoid creating new objects with `new` in your `player.update()`, since it will be slow due to the browser searching for more memory and the garbage collector spending time cleaning up the old objects.

Below is a snipped that should do what you are after.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
   
   div {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 170px;
    height: 30px;
   }
   
   button {
    width: 75px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font:-style: Lucida Console;
    font-size: 20px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
    color: #FFFFFFFF;
    background-color: #333333FF;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
   }
   
   button:hover {
    background-color: #777777FF;
   }
   
   button:active {
    background-color: #AAAAAAFF;
   }
   
   .top {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
   
   .bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 1px;
   }
   
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <button id="jumpButton" class="top">↑</button>
  <div>
   <button id="leftButton" class="bottom">←</button>
   <button id="rightButton" class="bottom">→</button>
  </div>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  void function() {
  
   "use strict";
   
   // Variables
   var canvasWidth = 180;
   var canvasHeight = 160;
   var canvas = null;
   var ctx = null;
   var player = null;
   
   var jumpButton = null;
   var leftButton = null;
   var rightButton = null;
   
   // Classes
   function Player(x,y) {
    // Position
    this.x = x || 0.0; // Using || in JS means use this second value if the first is null or undefined
    this.y = y || 0.0;
    
    // Velocity
    this.dx = 0.0;
    this.dy = 0.0;
    
    // Input
    this.isJumping = false; // Extra boolean to stop the player from jumping in mid-air
    this.isJumpDown = false;
    this.isLeftDown = false;
    this.isRightDown = false;
   }
   
   Player.prototype = {
    WIDTH: 10.0,
    HEIGHT: 20.0,
    
    SIDE_SPEED: 1.0,
    JUMP_SPEED: 4.0,
    FALL_SPEED: 0.2,
   
    tick: function() {
     // Input
     if (this.isLeftDown) {
      this.dx = -this.SIDE_SPEED;
     } else if (this.isRightDown) {
      this.dx = +this.SIDE_SPEED;
     } else {
      this.dx = 0.0;
     }
     
     if (this.isJumpDown && !this.isJumping) {
      this.isJumping = true;
      this.dy = -this.JUMP_SPEED;
     }
     
     // Falling
     if (this.isJumping) {
      this.dy += this.FALL_SPEED;
      
      if (this.y + this.dy > canvasHeight - this.HEIGHT) {
       this.y = canvasHeight - this.HEIGHT;
       this.dy = 0.0;
       this.isJumping = false;
      }
     }
     
     // Left/Right boundaries
     if (this.x < -this.WIDTH) {
      this.x = canvasWidth;
     } else if (this.x > canvasWidth) {
      this.x = -this.WIDTH;
     }
    
     this.x += this.dx;
     this.y += this.dy;
    },
    
    render: function(ctx) {
     ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
     ctx.fillStyle = "darkred";
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.rect(this.x,this.y,this.WIDTH,this.HEIGHT);
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.stroke();
    }
   };
   
   // Functions
   
   // Button event listeners
   function onJumpDown(e) {
    player.isJumpDown = true;
   }
   
   function onJumpUp(e) {
    player.isJumpDown = false;
   }
   
   function onLeftDown(e) {
    player.isLeftDown = true;
   }
   
   function onLeftUp(e) {
    player.isLeftDown = false;
   }
   
   function onRightDown(e) {
    player.isRightDown = true;
   }
   
   function onRightUp(e) {
    player.isRightDown = false;
   }
   
   // Game loop
   function loop() {
    // Tick
    player.tick();
    
    // Render
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    
    player.render(ctx);
    
    //
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   }
   
   // Entry point (this function runs first, window.onload)
   onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    jumpButton = document.getElementById("jumpButton");
    leftButton = document.getElementById("leftButton");
    rightButton = document.getElementById("rightButton");
    
    jumpButton.onmousedown = onJumpDown;
    jumpButton.onmouseup = onJumpUp;
    
    leftButton.onmousedown = onLeftDown;
    leftButton.onmouseup = onLeftUp;
    
    rightButton.onmousedown = onRightDown;
    rightButton.onmouseup = onRightUp;
    
    player = new Player(85.0,140.0);
    
    loop();
   }
  
  }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works on its own. However I can't get it to work with the code in my code snippets.